# ElasticSearch C# Nest Getting top words with 5.1

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticSearch object with these fields:

```
[Keyword]
public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
[Text]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

And, before I used to get the top Tags, in all the documents, using this code:

```
var Match = Driver.Search<Metadata>(_ => _
                  .Query(Q => Q
                  .Term(P => P.Category, (int)Category)
                     && Q.Term(P => P.Type, (int)Type))
                  .FielddataFields(F => F.Fields(F1 => F1.Tags, F2 => F2.Title))
                  .Aggregations(A => A.Terms("Tags", T => T.Field(F => F.Tags)
                  .Size(Limit))));
```

But with Elastic 5.1, I get an error 400 with this hint:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
>   [Tags] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the
>   inverted index.

Then the [ES documentation about parameter mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html) tells you "It usually doesn’t make sense to do so" and to "have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword field with doc_values enabled for aggregations".

But the only doc with this is for 5.0, and the same page for 5.1 seem to not exist.

Now, 5.1 has a page about [Term Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) that seems to cover what I need, but there is absolutely nothing to be found in C# / Nest that I can use.

So, I'm trying to figure out how I can just get the top words, across all documents, from the Tags (where each tag is its own word; for example *"New York"* is not *"New"* and *"York"*) and the title (where each word is its own thing) in C#.

---

I need to edit this post because there seems to be a deeper problem. I wrote some test code that illustrates the issue:

Let's create a simple object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Keyword]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Text]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Text(Fielddata = true)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

create the index:

```
var Uri = new Uri(Constants.ELASTIC_CONNECTIONSTRING);
var Settings = new ConnectionSettings(Uri)
.DefaultIndex("test")
.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(_ => _)
.InferMappingFor<MyObject>(_ => _.IdProperty(P => P.Id));   
var D = new ElasticClient(Settings);
```

fill the index with random stuff:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var O = new MyObject
    {
        Id = i.ToString(),
        Category = (i % 2) == 0 ? "a" : "b",
        Keywords = (i % 3).ToString()
    };

    D.Index(O);
}
```

and do the query:

```
var m = D.Search<MyObject>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Term(P => P.Category, "a"))
    .Source(f => f.Includes(si => si.Fields(ff => ff.Keywords)))
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("Keywords", t => t
            .Field(f => f.Keywords)
            .Size(Limit)
        )
    )
);
```

It fails the same way as before, with a 400 and:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on 
>   [Keywords] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted
>   index.

but Fielddata is set to true on [Keywords], yet it keeps complaining about it.

so, let's get crazy and modify the class this way:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Text(Fielddata = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Text(Fielddata = true)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Text(Fielddata = true)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

that way everything is a Text and everything has Fielddata = true.. well, same result.

so, either I am really not understanding something simple, or it's broken or not documented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less common that you want [Fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-fielddata.html); for your particular search here where you want to return just the tags and the title fields from the search query, take a look at using [Source Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/source-filtering-usage.html) for this

```
var Match = client.Search<Metadata>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(P => P.Category, (int)Category) && q
        .Term(P => P.Type, (int)Type)
    )
    .Source(f => f
        .Includes(si => si
            .Fields(
                ff => ff.Tags, 
                ff => ff.Title
            )
        )
    )
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("Tags", t => t
            .Field(f => f.Tags)
            .Size(Limit)
        )
    )
);
```

Fielddata needs to *uninvert* the inverted index into an in memory structure for aggregations and sorting. Whilst accessing this data can be very fast, it can also consume a lot of memory for a large data set.

**EDIT:**

Within your edit, I don't see anywhere where you *create* the index and explicitly map your `MyObject` POCO; without explicitly creating the index and mapping the POCO, Elasticsearch will automatically create the index and infer the mapping for `MyObject` based on the first json document that it receives, meaning `Keywords` will be mapped as a `text` field with a `keyword` [multi_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and Fielddata will not be enabled on the `text` field mapping.

Here's an example to demonstrate it all working

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "test";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
            .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s)
            .InferMappingFor<MyObject>(m => m
                .IdProperty(p => p.Id)
            );

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyObject>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );

    var objs = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i =>
        new MyObject
        {
            Id = i.ToString(),
            Category = (i % 2) == 0 ? "a" : "b",
            Keywords = (i % 3).ToString()
        });

    client.IndexMany(objs);

    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<MyObject>(s => s
        .Query(q => q.Term(P => P.Category, "a"))
        .Source(f => f.Includes(si => si.Fields(ff => ff.Keywords)))
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("Keywords", t => t
                .Field(f => f.Keywords)
                .Size(10)
            )
        )
    );

}

public class MyObject
{
    [Keyword]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Text]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Text(Fielddata = true)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

This returns

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 0.9808292,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "myobject",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 0.9808292,
        "_source" : {
          "Keywords" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "myobject",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "Keywords" : "0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "myobject",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.13353139,
        "_source" : {
          "Keywords" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "myobject",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.13353139,
        "_source" : {
          "Keywords" : "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "myobject",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 0.13353139,
        "_source" : {
          "Keywords" : "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "Keywords" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "0",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You might also consider mapping `Keywords` as a `text` field with a `keyword` multi_field, using the `text` field for unstructured search and the `keyword` for sorting, aggregations and structured search. This way, you get the best of both worlds and don't need to enable Fielddata

```
client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<MyObject>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.Keywords)
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Keyword(k => k
                            .Name("keyword")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

then in search use

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyObject>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Term(P => P.Category, "a"))
    .Source(f => f.Includes(si => si.Fields(ff => ff.Keywords)))
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("Keywords", t => t
            .Field(f => f.Keywords.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Size(10)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: we're talking 10million docs, roughly 500 tags; is the size proportional to the number of documents or the variety of tags? - would it make more sense that I manage this another way by having a dedicated table for tags and their count?

Comment: How do I set fielddata=true since tags are [keyword] and not [text]?

Comment: Now, I added an extra field just for the tags, it is a [text] field with FieldData set to true; and I still get an error 400 telling me to set FieldData to true on the very same field. Has anyone used the C# driver with this functionality to rule out any problem there? could this be related: https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/issues/643

Comment: ok, this clarifies everything I needed to know; I never called, in any of our code, the createindex function as I assumed it happened automatically.. looks like I have some fixing in order!

Comment: In order to explicitly map (with NEST doing inference from POCO property types, attributes or using fluent mapping), you have to either call `.Map<T>` on the `.CreateIndex()` call at index creation time or call `.Map<T>()` _before_ mapping any documents. Take a look at the automapping documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/auto-map.html