# ElasticSearch - Filter stop words from Top words

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a list of documents I am indexing like this:

```
        ElasticIndex.CreateIndex(IndexName, _ => _
            .Mappings(__ => __
                .Map<AlbumMetadata>(
                    M => M.AutoMap()
                   .Properties(P => P.Text(T => T.Name(N => N.Keywords)
                       .Analyzer("stop")
                       .Fields(F => F.Keyword(K => K.Name("keywords"))))))));
```

In my class *AlbumMetaData*, the field Keywords is a list:

```
    [Keyword]
    public List<string> Keywords            { get; set; }
```

When I want to retrieve the top terms, I do the following query (you can ignore *Category* and *Type*, they're not relevant to the problem):

```
        var Match = Driver.Search<AlbumMetadata>(_ => _
            .Query(Q => Q
                .Term(P => P.Category, (int)Category) && Q
                .Term(P => P.Type, (int)Type))
            .Source(F => F.Includes(S => S.Fields(L => L.Keywords)))
            .Aggregations(A => A
                .Terms("Tags", T => T
                    .Field(E => E.Keywords)
                    .Size(Limit)
            )
        ));

        var Tags = Match.Aggs.Terms("Tags").Buckets.ToDictionary(K => K.Key, V => V.DocCount);
```

The problem is that in the output, I get some stop words as well as some symbols, like / - & |

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:
In order to clarify the question, here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have documents that have titles (full English sentences) and tags (list of single words, sometimes a tag is a two word tag).

I need to be able to perform a search that will find documents based on the title and tags (and ideally using word stems, ignoring plurals, etc).
I also need to extract the list of top words. The Keywords list is a concatenation of all words from the title and all the entries from the tags list.

Is the way I create the index appropriate in this context? Also, is the way I do the aggregation the right way?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things:

1. When you create the index, `.AutoMap()` on the mapping will infer Elasticsearch field datatypes from the POCO property types and the attributes applied to them. Then, `.Properties()` overrides any of these inferred mappings. So, the end result of your mapping for `Keywords` is a [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) datatype field with the `stop` analyzer applied, and a `multi-field` sub field of `"keywords"` (queryable via `"keywords.keywords"`), set as a [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype.
2. The aggregation is running on the `"keywords"` `text` field with the `stop` analyzer applied. The `stop` analyzer [uses English stop words by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/stopwords.html), but you can configure the `stop` analyzer with other stop words by defining a custom `stop` analyzer in the index. The `stop` analyzer will not remove symbols like `/`, `-`, `&` and `|`.
3. With a terms aggregation, you generally want to get back aggregations on the verbatim terms for a field, which you can get with your mapping by using the `"keywords.keywords"` field in the aggregation. You can apply a [`normalizer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) to a `keyword` field which is similar to an analyzer, except it produces only one token. This is because a `keyword` field uses [`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), an on-disk columnar data structure that is suited for well performing, large scale aggregations.

   You can run the aggregation on a `text` field too as you're doing, but you also need to enable [`fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) and be aware of how it works. `text` fields can't use `doc_values`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Russ; it's clarifying a few things for me. I have edited the question to explain what I am trying to achieve because I'm wondering if the way I index the documents make sense in that context. Also, I read about the normalizer and it seems to be something I could really use: do you have any reference about how it is used with Nest?

Comment: No written reference for `normalizer`. Take a look at the source; here's the test for `keyword` data type that sets a normalizer: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Tests/Mapping/Types/Core/Keyword/KeywordPropertyTests.cs#L22 and the static method it calls https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Tests/Analysis/Normalizers/NormalizerUsageTests.cs#L34-L42. Basically, a normalizer is like an analyzer but is **restricted to outputting one token/term only**

Comment: so, If I understand correctly: I am mapping Keywords as text for text search and mapping is also as a Keyword type for tags aggregation and this is as expected. I do not understand the keyword.keyword sub-field concept? In fact the code was based on help you gave me on another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903195/elasticsearch-c-sharp-nest-getting-top-words-with-5-1?rq=1) but I'm still very confused with Elastic's terminology, etc probably because I only looked at it from Nest's perspective and documentation.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on `multi fields` as I think it'll help clear it up: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html if it doesn't let me know :) I'm working on new documentation for NEST that should also help, which will go onto the site when it's ready: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/enhancement/great-docs-update/docs/client-concepts/high-level/mapping/multi-fields.asciidoc

Comment: I read the documents about multi fields and it totally made sense; that opens another question: if I have 2 analyzers (like text and English in the example), it looks like I have to run 2 queries to maximize results, but is it possible for example to run analyzers combined sequentially: like StopWords + English (to remove stop words and keep stems) and run the same process on the query so the query text doesn't have stop words and uses stems?

Comment: @Thomas I'd recommend opening another question with that :)

Comment: @Thomas, also take a sneak preview at: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/enhancement/great-docs-update/docs/client-concepts/high-level/analysis/writing-analyzers.asciidoc